# What is the difference of dynamic shared memory as kernel attribute and kernel argument in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

Wer are using dynamic shared memory in our CUDA kernels. We are setting the size of the shared memory for each kernel using the **driver API** `cuFuncSetAttribute` and `CU_FUNC_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_DYNAMIC_SHARED_SIZE_BYTES`.

The kernel is then launched using [`cuLaunchKernel`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html#group__CUDA__EXEC_1gb8f3dc3031b40da29d5f9a7139e52e15) where in the docs one of the parameter is `unsigned int sharedMemBytes`. This parameter is defined to set

> Dynamic shared-memory size per thread block in bytes

This means I can set the dynamic memory size per **kernel attribute** and additionally I can set the shared memory size per **kernel call**.

Does this mean I can override the kernel attribute? Which one wins?

Answer (score 2):

- kernel attribute -> **maximum** value
- Launch configuration field -> **actual** value

Says so right in the name: `MAX_DYNAMIC_SHARED_SIZE_BYTES` vs `sharedMemBytes`. Note the MAX prefix :-)

Setting a different maximum value may effect the GPU's behavior when running the kernel, e.g. the allocation of regular L1 cache for use by the kernel (as in some/most NVIDIA GPU micro-architectures, shared memory is repurposed L1 cache, and their total amount is fixed but the proportions aren't; see also [§16.6.4 of the CUDA C++ Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-7-x)).

Now, it's true that passing a specific amount of shared memory could have implicitly done whatever setting maximum does; but - either that has somewhat of an overhead, or - it's just how NVIDIA has chosen to do things.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Do you know what would happen if I specify less size in the kernel call that I have defined in the kernel attribute. Since it is always evaluated at kernel launch time, what would be the effect to set some maximum?

Comment: @msedi The attribute is an opt-in if you want to use more than 48KB of shared memory per block. See the architecture-specific shared memory documentation e.g. for  [Volta/Turing](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-7-x).

Comment: @msedi The only reason I can think of for this kind of API is that setting the attribute has some overhead and therefore you don't want to do it at every launch when needed / not at all when not needed.

Comment: @paleonix: Integrated your comment into my answer.

Comment: Already seen and gave +1 ;)